# scrapy FilesPipeline if file_urls ownload again

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am new in scrapy.

I use `FilesPipeline` to download some .pdf file.

I found that **if the value of `file_urls` of Scrapy.Item is same, the downloading process will not start again.**

What I need is download again.

How can I solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `_onsuccess` function to your pipeline to override it. (Copy it from `FilesPipelines`).

It looks like this:

```
    def media_to_download(self, request, info, *, item=None):
        def _onsuccess(result):
            if not result:
                return  # returning None force download

            last_modified = result.get('last_modified', None)
            if not last_modified:
                return  # returning None force download

            
            age_seconds = time.time() - last_modified
            age_days = age_seconds / 60 / 60 / 24
            if age_days > self.expires:
                return  # returning None force download

            referer = referer_str(request)
            logger.debug(
                'File (uptodate): Downloaded %(medianame)s from %(request)s '
                'referred in <%(referer)s>',
                {'medianame': self.MEDIA_NAME, 'request': request,
                 'referer': referer},
                extra={'spider': info.spider}
            )
    AND MORE CODE HERE THAT I DIDN'T COPY
```

Just add a return to skip the "uptodate" part and download anyway.

```
    def media_to_download(self, request, info, *, item=None):
        def _onsuccess(result):
            if not result:
                return  # returning None force download

            last_modified = result.get('last_modified', None)
            if not last_modified:
                return  # returning None force download

            
            age_seconds = time.time() - last_modified
            age_days = age_seconds / 60 / 60 / 24
            if age_days > self.expires:
                return  # returning None force download

            return    # force download
```

(You can also overwrite the function inside `FilesPipeline`, but I don't recommend to do it).

Also, remember to activate your custom pipeline and add other functions you need.

Your pipelines.py file should look like this now:

```
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
from scrapy.http import Request
import logging
import time
from twisted.internet import defer
from scrapy.utils.log import failure_to_exc_info

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class TempPipeline():

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item

class ProcessPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        urls = ItemAdapter(item).get(self.files_urls_field, [])
        return [Request(u) for u in urls]

    def media_to_download(self, request, info, *, item=None):
        def _onsuccess(result):
            if not result:
                return  # returning None force download

            last_modified = result.get('last_modified', None)
            if not last_modified:
                return  # returning None force download

            age_seconds = time.time() - last_modified
            age_days = age_seconds / 60 / 60 / 24
            if age_days > self.expires:
                return  # returning None force download

            return

        path = self.file_path(request, info=info, item=item)
        dfd = defer.maybeDeferred(self.store.stat_file, path, info)
        dfd.addCallbacks(_onsuccess, lambda _: None)
        dfd.addErrback(
            lambda f:
            logger.error(self.__class__.__name__ + '.store.stat_file',
                         exc_info=failure_to_exc_info(f),
                         extra={'spider': info.spider})
        )
        return dfd
```

Comment: At Last, I found that the reason of why download twice of same file_urls is not work.
The scrapy cache all file_urls in a stack.
 If Scrapy found the new file_urls is same in the stack, Scapy will skip downlad it.
`I donot found a boolean param to stop the feature`.